# best way to POST an image in node?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, request, http-post

what's the best way to upload some images to a service and capture the response, in node?

I'm looking to upload some images much like

```
curl -F media=@$MEDIAFILE $URL
```

would do.

I've got the [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) working with a stream and pipe, but I can't see how to capture the output/response.

```
// define a read stream from our source file
var inFile = 'media/uploads/images/abby.jpg';
var source = fs.createReadStream(inFile);

// pipe data to POST request
source.pipe(request.post(wcUrl)
    .on('error', function(error){
        console.log("ERROR:", error);
    })
    .on('response', function(response, p1, p2){
        console.log(Object.keys(response));
        console.log('headers', response.headers);
        console.log('statusCode', response.statusCode);
        console.log('body', response.body);
    })

);
```

I can see the statusCode is a 200 response OK, but can't get at the body of the response. None of the returned fields seem to have useful data in.

```
[ '_readableState',
  'readable',
  'domain',
  '_events',
  '_eventsCount',
  '_maxListeners',
  'socket',
  'connection',
  'httpVersionMajor',
  'httpVersionMinor',
  'httpVersion',
  'complete',
  'headers',
  'rawHeaders',
  'trailers',
  'rawTrailers',
  'upgrade',
  'url',
  'method',
  'statusCode',
  'statusMessage',
  'client',
  '_consuming',
  '_dumped',
  'req',
  'request',
  'toJSON',
  'caseless' ]
headers { server: 'nginx/1.8.0',
  date: 'Thu, 31 Dec 2015 00:00:34 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/plain',
  'content-length': '109',
  connection: 'close' }
statusCode 200
body undefined
```

Most of the request package examples are using forms or multipart, whereas I just want to send a simple image file. 
Perhaps there's another more suitable nodey way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

aha, i have to nest another event inside the response:

```
.on('response', function(response, p1, p2) {
  response.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('finalData', data.toString() );
    console.log('received ' + data.length + ' bytes of compressed data');
  });
```

This does seem very convoluted, so still interested if there's a simpler way.